# Does react router override URL Routing of app.get('/ping'?

Tags: node.js, api, express, react-router, url-routing

I currently have a shared hosting (CPanel) that is serving out a static build of Node.JS for the client side code. On the same origin and shared hosting I have an express server running, shown below:

```
const express = require('express')
const path = require('path')
const app = express()

const express = require('express')
const path = require('path')
const app = express()

// This doesn't work
app.get('/ping', (req, res) => {
  return res.send('pong')
})

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')))


app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'))
})

app.listen(8080) (req, res) => {
  return res.send('pong')
})

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')))

// This serves out the static build of the client side code (App.js) - and works
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'))
})

app.listen(8080)
```

I am trying to create an API for the server side to interact with the client side. The main app serves perfectly when I access the root '/'. However, I cant seem to get this code to work on the server side when I try to access this portion of the API:

```
app.get('/ping', (req, res) => {
      return res.send('pong')
    })
```

When I access the URL with the '/ping' it just gives me a blank screen without saying 'pong'. However, in the static build, I am using a BrowserRouter which perfectly assigns a URL to a page when I access '/rooms/id' in the URL:

```
 function App() {
  return (

    <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" exact component={CreateRoom} />
        <Route path="/room/:roomID" component={Room} />
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

Is this client side code conflicting with my server side code? How else do I get an API to serve my client side stuff and my server side stuff on the same origin?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it:

I needed a folder on the root directory called 'ping'.

This is my first time building an API, so hopefully im doing this properly!